# Javascript code working locally but does not work on live site

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have small javascript code used to give class to images based on the height and width ratio.
if ratio between width and height is between 1.05 and 0.95 give class of Square, greater than 1.8 give class of fulllandscape, if between 1.8 and 1.05 landscape, smaller than 0.95 then portrait.

the code works fine locally. It adds right classes based on these ratio.

But on my live site, it's not assigning the right classes. It seems to give class "square" as default and not correctly assign the right class.

I checked the syntex and double checked the math but it still does not work.

Even running the code snippet, it seems to work but not on my live site.

[live site where it doesn't work](http://innohome.kr/product/%EB%AC%BC%EB%B0%A9%EC%9A%B8-%EC%88%98%EC%A0%80%EB%B0%9B%EC%B9%A8-%EB%B0%95%EC%84%A0%EB%AF%BC-%EC%9E%91%EA%B0%80/1696/category/1/display/3/)

It is giving class square to all the images.

Checking the console, it doesn't seem to show anything related to this code and I can't pinpoint the issue.

Please help me find what's wrong and help me fix this issue.

Apprecite all the help.

```js
function applyImageClass(image) {
  var h = (image) ? image.height() : 0;
  if (h > 0) {
    var ratio = image.width() / h;
    if (ratio <= 1.05 && ratio >= 0.95) {
      image.addClass('square');
    } else if (ratio >= 1.8) {
      image.addClass('fulllandscape');
    } else if (ratio < 1.8 && ratio > 1.05) {
      image.addClass('landscape');
    } else if (ratio < 0.95) {
      image.addClass('portrait');
    }
  }
}

$(window).on('load', function() {
  // Find all images contained in any element that has any of the classes
  $('.imagesection').find('img').each(function() {
    // Call the function for each one of the matched elements
    applyImageClass($(this));
  });
});
```

```css
.detailsection img{max-width:800px;}

.imagesection {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.imagesection img {
  float: left;
}

.imagesection img.fulllandscape {
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.imagesection img.landscape {
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 49%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 3% 3%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.imagesection img.portrait {
  width: 49%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  padding: 3% 10%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.imagesection img.square {
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 3% 3%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="image.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="image2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="detailsection">

    <!--Detail Title Image-->
    <div class="titlepg">
      <img src="http://innofeel60.cafe24.com/web/productdetail/kitchendining/%EB%AC%BC%EB%B0%A9%EC%9A%B8%EC%88%98%EC%A0%80%EB%B0%9B%EC%B9%A8/title.jpg" alt="" class="titlepg">
    </div>
    <!--Detail Title Image-->


    <!--Image section-->
    <div class="imagesection">
      <img src="http://innofeel60.cafe24.com/web/productdetail/kitchendining/%EB%AC%BC%EB%B0%A9%EC%9A%B8%EC%88%98%EC%A0%80%EB%B0%9B%EC%B9%A8/img/droplet1.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://innofeel60.cafe24.com/web/productdetail/kitchendining/%EB%AC%BC%EB%B0%A9%EC%9A%B8%EC%88%98%EC%A0%80%EB%B0%9B%EC%B9%A8/img/droplet2.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://innofeel60.cafe24.com/web/productdetail/kitchendining/%EB%AC%BC%EB%B0%A9%EC%9A%B8%EC%88%98%EC%A0%80%EB%B0%9B%EC%B9%A8/img/droplet3.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://innofeel60.cafe24.com/web/productdetail/kitchendining/%EB%AC%BC%EB%B0%A9%EC%9A%B8%EC%88%98%EC%A0%80%EB%B0%9B%EC%B9%A8/img/droplet4.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://innofeel60.cafe24.com/web/productdetail/kitchendining/%EB%AC%BC%EB%B0%A9%EC%9A%B8%EC%88%98%EC%A0%80%EB%B0%9B%EC%B9%A8/img/droplet11.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://innofeel60.cafe24.com/web/productdetail/kitchendining/%EB%AC%BC%EB%B0%A9%EC%9A%B8%EC%88%98%EC%A0%80%EB%B0%9B%EC%B9%A8/img/droplet5.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://innofeel60.cafe24.com/web/productdetail/kitchendining/%EB%AC%BC%EB%B0%A9%EC%9A%B8%EC%88%98%EC%A0%80%EB%B0%9B%EC%B9%A8/img/droplet6.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://innofeel60.cafe24.com/web/productdetail/kitchendining/%EB%AC%BC%EB%B0%A9%EC%9A%B8%EC%88%98%EC%A0%80%EB%B0%9B%EC%B9%A8/img/droplet7.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://innofeel60.cafe24.com/web/productdetail/kitchendining/%EB%AC%BC%EB%B0%A9%EC%9A%B8%EC%88%98%EC%A0%80%EB%B0%9B%EC%B9%A8/img/droplet8.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://innofeel60.cafe24.com/web/productdetail/kitchendining/%EB%AC%BC%EB%B0%A9%EC%9A%B8%EC%88%98%EC%A0%80%EB%B0%9B%EC%B9%A8/img/droplet12.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://innofeel60.cafe24.com/web/productdetail/kitchendining/%EB%AC%BC%EB%B0%A9%EC%9A%B8%EC%88%98%EC%A0%80%EB%B0%9B%EC%B9%A8/img/droplet9.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://innofeel60.cafe24.com/web/productdetail/kitchendining/%EB%AC%BC%EB%B0%A9%EC%9A%B8%EC%88%98%EC%A0%80%EB%B0%9B%EC%B9%A8/img/droplet10.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://innofeel60.cafe24.com/web/productdetail/kitchendining/%EB%AC%BC%EB%B0%A9%EC%9A%B8%EC%88%98%EC%A0%80%EB%B0%9B%EC%B9%A8/img/DSC_8836.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://innofeel60.cafe24.com/web/productdetail/kitchendining/%EB%AC%BC%EB%B0%A9%EC%9A%B8%EC%88%98%EC%A0%80%EB%B0%9B%EC%B9%A8/img/DSC_8662.jpg" alt="">

    </div>
    <!--Image section-->


  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are you including the same version of jquery twice, from different sources?

Comment: Move `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` to the top of the page and delete the other jQuery

Comment: You will want to attach to the image load event, not just the page load.  Otherwise width and height will not yet be known..

Comment: @Keith images should be loaded after window.onload, if not the browser has a bug.

Comment: @epascarello  It's not that the browser has a bug, it's that he's using an image loader.

Comment: I've down voted this because the code in the question doesn't represent the actual code that's causing the problems. The actual code uses an image loader which makes the whole scenario vastly different from what is described in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your using an image loader, I assume it's some sort of scroll into view loader etc.

Problem is, your using `window.onload` event, this fires when the DOM is loaded & images are ready etc, but your loader is going to bypass that.

So it's better to attach to the image load event directly instead.

eg.

```
$('.imagesection').find('img').each(function() {
  $(this).load(applyImageClass.bind(null, $(this)));
});
```

> Note:  don't place this code inside `window.onload` event now, as we
>   don't want to wait for all images to load.  An added bonus, for slow
>   loading images we now don't wait for all images to load first.

```js
function applyImageClass(image) {
  var h = (image) ? image.height() : 0;
  if (h > 0) {
    var ratio = image.width() / h;
    if (ratio <= 1.05 && ratio >= 0.95) {
      image.addClass('square');
    } else if (ratio >= 1.8) {
      image.addClass('fulllandscape');
    } else if (ratio < 1.8 && ratio > 1.05) {
      image.addClass('landscape');
    } else if (ratio < 0.95) {
      image.addClass('portrait');
    }
  }
}

$('.imagesection').find('img').each(function() {
  $(this).load(applyImageClass.bind(null, $(this)));
});
```

```css
.detailsection img{max-width:800px;}

.imagesection {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.imagesection img {
  float: left;
}

.imagesection img.fulllandscape {
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.imagesection img.landscape {
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 49%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 3% 3%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.imagesection img.portrait {
  width: 49%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  padding: 3% 10%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.imagesection img.square {
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 3% 3%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="image.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="image2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="detailsection">

    <!--Detail Title Image-->
    <div class="titlepg">
      <img src="http://innofeel60.cafe24.com/web/productdetail/kitchendining/%EB%AC%BC%EB%B0%A9%EC%9A%B8%EC%88%98%EC%A0%80%EB%B0%9B%EC%B9%A8/title.jpg" alt="" class="titlepg">
    </div>
    <!--Detail Title Image-->


    <!--Image section-->
    <div class="imagesection">
      <img src="http://innofeel60.cafe24.com/web/productdetail/kitchendining/%EB%AC%BC%EB%B0%A9%EC%9A%B8%EC%88%98%EC%A0%80%EB%B0%9B%EC%B9%A8/img/droplet1.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://innofeel60.cafe24.com/web/productdetail/kitchendining/%EB%AC%BC%EB%B0%A9%EC%9A%B8%EC%88%98%EC%A0%80%EB%B0%9B%EC%B9%A8/img/droplet2.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://innofeel60.cafe24.com/web/productdetail/kitchendining/%EB%AC%BC%EB%B0%A9%EC%9A%B8%EC%88%98%EC%A0%80%EB%B0%9B%EC%B9%A8/img/droplet3.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://innofeel60.cafe24.com/web/productdetail/kitchendining/%EB%AC%BC%EB%B0%A9%EC%9A%B8%EC%88%98%EC%A0%80%EB%B0%9B%EC%B9%A8/img/droplet4.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://innofeel60.cafe24.com/web/productdetail/kitchendining/%EB%AC%BC%EB%B0%A9%EC%9A%B8%EC%88%98%EC%A0%80%EB%B0%9B%EC%B9%A8/img/droplet11.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://innofeel60.cafe24.com/web/productdetail/kitchendining/%EB%AC%BC%EB%B0%A9%EC%9A%B8%EC%88%98%EC%A0%80%EB%B0%9B%EC%B9%A8/img/droplet5.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://innofeel60.cafe24.com/web/productdetail/kitchendining/%EB%AC%BC%EB%B0%A9%EC%9A%B8%EC%88%98%EC%A0%80%EB%B0%9B%EC%B9%A8/img/droplet6.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://innofeel60.cafe24.com/web/productdetail/kitchendining/%EB%AC%BC%EB%B0%A9%EC%9A%B8%EC%88%98%EC%A0%80%EB%B0%9B%EC%B9%A8/img/droplet7.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://innofeel60.cafe24.com/web/productdetail/kitchendining/%EB%AC%BC%EB%B0%A9%EC%9A%B8%EC%88%98%EC%A0%80%EB%B0%9B%EC%B9%A8/img/droplet8.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://innofeel60.cafe24.com/web/productdetail/kitchendining/%EB%AC%BC%EB%B0%A9%EC%9A%B8%EC%88%98%EC%A0%80%EB%B0%9B%EC%B9%A8/img/droplet12.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://innofeel60.cafe24.com/web/productdetail/kitchendining/%EB%AC%BC%EB%B0%A9%EC%9A%B8%EC%88%98%EC%A0%80%EB%B0%9B%EC%B9%A8/img/droplet9.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://innofeel60.cafe24.com/web/productdetail/kitchendining/%EB%AC%BC%EB%B0%A9%EC%9A%B8%EC%88%98%EC%A0%80%EB%B0%9B%EC%B9%A8/img/droplet10.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://innofeel60.cafe24.com/web/productdetail/kitchendining/%EB%AC%BC%EB%B0%A9%EC%9A%B8%EC%88%98%EC%A0%80%EB%B0%9B%EC%B9%A8/img/DSC_8836.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://innofeel60.cafe24.com/web/productdetail/kitchendining/%EB%AC%BC%EB%B0%A9%EC%9A%B8%EC%88%98%EC%A0%80%EB%B0%9B%EC%B9%A8/img/DSC_8662.jpg" alt="">

    </div>
    <!--Image section-->


  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank You so much. This solved the problem. I had no idea about the image loader.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of errors on your page that say that scripts couldn't be loaded and there's also a "ReferenceError: event is not defined"

F12 in your browser opens the dev console with the log. This gives you more details. I guess you need to fix those errors.